# Storing images with LINQ to SQL: Converting byte array or stream to Binary

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, arrays

I am working with LINQ to SQL and my image fields are treated as Binary.  It's no big issue to convert the Binary type to byte[] (you can just use the ToArray() method of the Binary object) when I need to render the images, but can someone tell me how to turn either a byte[] or Stream object into the Binary object so I can save it back to the database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351422.aspx):

```
public Binary(byte[] value)
```

like this:

```
yourObj.BinaryProperty = new Binary(bytes);
```