# Save files in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, file-upload, linq-to-sql, blobstore

I have a handler which takes blolbs from Javascript code and save them in a folder, this solution is to upload big files. But now I want to save the data to database
I have created a Linq-to-SQL model and I have created a database with fields id,name,data,filetype
Can anyone help me on saving the data in db?

This is my code:

```
namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Handler
    /// </summary>
    public class Handler : IHttpHandler
    {
        LinfSqlDataContext LINQSql = new LinfSqlDataContext();
        testfilesave ft = new testfilesave();
        public static void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
        {

            //argument-checking here.
            try
            {

                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
                {
                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[context.Request.ContentLength];
                context.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, context.Request.ContentLength);
                string fileName = context.Request.Headers.Get("X_FILE_NAME");

                string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + fileName);
                if (context.Request.Headers.Get("X_Blob_Number") == "0")
                {
                    if (File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        File.Delete(filePath);
                    }
                }
                AppendAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + fileName), buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are there any exceptions?

Comment: What **datatype** are your columns? And which **version** of SQL Server are you using??

Comment: @marc_s SQL SERVER 2008 andmy data field in my table that is the most important which I want to save my file is Varbinary(max)

Comment: @Oluwafemi I did not undestand what exception you mean. but the code I wrote will save the sliced file piece by piece in a folder
what I want to do now is to save it in my table in sql server

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save image into sql-server using linq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877347/how-to-save-image-into-sql-server-using-linq)